# Update object in nested json Angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

The code below shows a jSON server in a url , so how can i change for example the players name and their numbers using AngularJs.
Thank you.

```
{
"id": 1,
"Team": "Arsenal",
"Manager": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "Name":"Arsene_Wenger",
  "Players": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "Name": "Welbeck",
      "Number": "23"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "Name": "Ramsey",
      "Number": "16"
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

Comment: Change it where, on the server? If so, you would have to get the data from the server, change it on the view, then send the data back.

Comment: see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Answer (score 0):

Simply bind a ng-model on the HTML side, for instance:

```
<div ng-repeat="player in Football.Manager[0].Players;">
 <input type="text" ng-model="player.Name" > {{player.Name}}</input>
 <input type="text" ng-model="player.Number" >{{player.Number}}</input>
</div>
```

Then, whenever the model is changed in HTML it will affect the JSON model you got.